# FsSql Not working when Parameterizing Columns

Tags: postgresql, f#, fssql

Using `F#` , `FsSql` and `PostGres`

So I'm using this function

```
let getSqlParameter value = 
    let uniqueKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")
    let key = (sprintf "@%s" uniqueKey)
    (key,Sql.Parameter.make(key,value))
```

to get me a parameter of anything I pass in dynamically

Which I then append to a query and I get something like this

```
select * from (select * from mytable) as innerQuery where @a29c575b69bb4629a9971dac2808b445 LIKE '%@9e3485fdf99249e5ad6adb6405f5f5ca%'
```

Then I take a collection of these and pass them off

`Sql.asyncExecReader connectionManager query parameters`

The problem that I'm having is that when I don't run this through my parameterization engine, it works fine. When I do, it doesn't work. It just returns empty sets.

The only thing I can think of is that the column names can't be parameterized. This is a problem because they're coming from the client. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the answer here is that you can't parameterize column names as far as I can tell.

What I ended up doing was creating a whitelist of acceptable column names and then compare what was coming in to my whitelist. If it doesn't exist then I drop it.

By far a sub-optimal solution. I really wish there was a way to do this.

Comment: It wouldn't make any sense. Names aren't parameters. For all RDBMS products, the query is the program that gets compiled into an execution plan based on the table schema, indexes, statistics. Changing the target *field* means that the execution plan is now useless and a new one would be needed. Might as well create a new query. Not unlike an F# function if you try to pass the wrong type as input

Comment: BTW that query is rather strange - first a `LIKE '%sdf%` query will scan the *entire* table without benefit of indexing. Second, the "parameters" are treated as if they were string replacement parameters. That `LIKE` clause will search for anything containing `@9e3485fdf9...`, not any provided parameter value. Perhaps you should look into Full Text Search indexes?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'll look into the FTS indexes. Thanks